# Oracle XML table export objecttype not giving

Tags: xml, oracle, export, varchar2

If I do a export of a table with a field of type `varchar2(12 char)` or `varchar2(12 byte)` I only get in the XML file fields of type `varchar2(12)`. 
Can you get the object type of a `varchar2` field in the XML export file ?

example

```
create table TEST_XML 
( field1 varchar2(10 char)
, field2 varchar2(10 byte)
)
```

output in XML file is:

```
 <COL_LIST>
     <COL_LIST_ITEM>
        <NAME>FIELD1</NAME>
        <DATATYPE>VARCHAR2</DATATYPE>
        <LENGTH>10</LENGTH>
        <CHAR_SEMANTICS></CHAR_SEMANTICS>
     </COL_LIST_ITEM>
     <COL_LIST_ITEM>
        <NAME>FIELD2</NAME>
        <DATATYPE>VARCHAR2</DATATYPE>
        <LENGTH>10</LENGTH>
     </COL_LIST_ITEM>
```

I used the following statement that gives back a clob with the XML data

```
declare 
  hDDL number;
  hXfr number;
  oDDL clob;
begin 
  hDDL := dbms_metadata.open('TABLE');
  dbms_metadata.set_filter(hDDL, 'SCHEMA', '<owner>');
  dbms_metadata.set_filter(hDDL, 'NAME', 'TEST_XML');
  hXfr := sys.dbms_metadata.add_transform(hDDL, 'SXML');
  oDDL := sys.dbms_metadata.fetch_clob(hDDL);
  dbms_metadata.close(hDDL);
end;
```

Comment: how do you get this export?

Comment: i added the method how i got the export

Comment: you already get `<CHAR_SEMANTICS></CHAR_SEMANTICS>` for the first one, and nothing for `byte` which's the default one.